# How do I design a schema for an order which has both "packages" and "single items"?

Tags: sqlite, database-schema

For example, if I go to McDonald's I can order a Happy Meal *and* a Hamburger on the same purchase. But a Happy Meal is actually a collection of items that could be purchased individually (Happy MEal would be a "Package", for lack of a better word.)

This is what I have so far, but I know the customerOrderDetail must be wrong.

```
    CREATE TABLE "Menu" (
    "MenuID" Integer NOT NULL,
    "Title" Text NOT NULL,
    "SortOrder" Text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("MenuID") ,
    );

    CREATE TABLE "SingleItem" (
    "SingleItemID" Integer NOT NULL,
    "Name" Text,
    "MenuID" Integer,
    PRIMARY KEY ("SingleItemID") ,
    );

    CREATE TABLE "CustomerOrder" (
    "CustomerOrderID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Date" TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY ("CustomerOrderID") 
    );

    CREATE TABLE "CustomerOrderDetail" (
    "CustomerOrderDetailID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "CustomerOrderID" INTEGER,
    "SortOrder" INTEGER,
    "PackageID" INTEGER,
    "SingleItemID" INTEGER,
    "Quantity" INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY ("CustomerOrderDetailID") ,
    );

    CREATE TABLE "Package" (
    "PackageID" Integer NOT NULL,
    "MenuID" Integer NOT NULL,
    "PackageTypeID" Integer NOT NULL,
    "DateModified" Date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("PackageID") ,
    );

    CREATE TABLE "PackageDetail" (
    "PackageDetailID" Integer NOT NULL,
    "PackageID" Integer NOT NULL,
    "SingleItemID" Integer NOT NULL,
    "SingleItemOrder" Integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("PackageDetailID") ,
    );

    CREATE TABLE "PackageType" (
    "PackageTypeID" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Name" TEXT,
    "SortOrder" INTEGER,
    "Note" TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY ("PackageTypeID") 
    );
```

[imgur link to Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tYky.png)

Comment: A happy meal is a combination of several customer selections (one of several drinks and one of several burgers), isn't it?

Comment: Could you provide some sample content by adding a few lines of "insert into ..."? To make playing and demonstrating more convenient.